# Creating a Project Without Using a Single TRY-CATCH exception handling

Tags: c#, exception, error-handling

I want to centralize error handling by avoiding the messy try-catch blocks, I explored the global.asax and I notice
that every error occur in the application domain goes to the Application_Error block, so my question is, is this really possible? is all the possible error goes throug global.asax Application_Error block?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is not only possible, but done in many web applications as a catch all location for unhandled exceptions.

See [this article](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/030102.htm) on 15seconds (a bit old, but still relevant).